# Sorting python dictionary by inconsistant variables

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary and each item has varying attributes.

```
{ "Item1": { "Name" : "Tom", "Color" : "Blue", "Weight" = "10lb" }, "Item2": { "Name" : "Billy", "Weight" : "5lb" } }
```

The problem is I want to sort by Color, where the color for Item2 would be None because its not specified. So the sort would treat color as ""

I can loop through the entire dictionary and add `Color : ""` to anything missing the attribute but it is a really large dictionary and it needs to run relatively fast.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code.

Comment: well you provide a lambda function when you sort so you can handle the None case. also, seems like the wrong data structure for the job

Comment: Hint: the `dict.get` method has an optional default argument.

Comment: Use `.get(key, default)` when asking for the contents. So instead of simply `dict["Item1"]["Color"]`, use `dict["Item1"].get("Color", default="")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `dict.get('Color', default)` to supply a default value for colour.

If `d` is your dictionary:

```
In [20]: sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda k:d[k].get('Color', ''))
Out[20]: ['Item2', 'Item1']
```

Comment: I think you may probably skip `d.keys()`, just using `d` should suffice the requirement

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I believe your're right. [I tested it](https://repl.it/Jx7G/0) and it seemed to work correctly.

Comment: You're my hero. Thank you. I didn't realize you could pass defaults to a get. Python newbie here. And yes, d alone was sufficient